# Android studio failing to run adb

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the below error when trying to run the app through Android Studio on Ubuntu. Not sure why this error is coming even if the adb file exists in the location specified.

```
ERROR - application.impl.ApplicationImpl - java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/raghu/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a 64 bit machine,

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Have a [look at this link](https://codelatte.wordpress.com/2015/01/27/installing-the-android-sdk-on-ubuntu-14-04/).

Comment: No! "./home" is obviously and absurdly erronoeous

Comment: "." refers to the *current* directory, so prepending it to an absolute path will turn it into a non existent relative one.  Your suggestion is not only unecessary, but unworkable.

Comment: The third option of installing the packages helped. Thank you.